# Soporte MultiVentana para la App en TouchWiz de Samsung (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

Hoy he estado trasteando mis apps en un dispositivo `Samsung tab S2` que tiene lo de multiventana, pero cuando intento que mi app se vea en una parte de pantalla me sale un mensaje, app no soporta multiventana.

¿Que directivas se debe poner en el `AndroidManifest.xml` para que soporte multiventana?

**Editado**
He encontrado el siguiente hilo en [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1985240), pero no lo puedo trastear ya que no tengo ningún Samsung con la funcionalidad multiwindow de su capa de personalización `TouchWiz`.

Si alguien puede trastear y poner entero el `AndroidManifest.xml` en una respuesta, seria de agradecer.

Si se añade una animación para ver como se ajusta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Añadir soporte para Samsung/Android **Multi-Ventana** *(MultiTasking - MultiWindow)* a sus aplicaciones.

El problema o el inconveniente de muchas aplicaciones es que no admiten o no soportan aún la funcionalidad.

**Desarrolladores:** esto es lo que hay que hacer para añadir soporte a sus aplicaciones!

En realidad es bastante fácil. En su `AndroidManifest.xml`, haga lo siguiente:

*Haz tu aplicación aparezca en la barra de Multi-Ventana. Añadir la categoría intención `MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER` a la actividad principal lanzador de la aplicación, así justo debajo de la línea de `'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'`, añade:*

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
```

*Indica que está utilizando la biblioteca Multi-Ventana. Incluir lo siguiente justo antes de su `</application>` cerrar la etiqueta:*

```
<uses-library required="false" name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"> </uses-library>
```

Añadir los **metadatos** para indicar que su aplicación es compatible Multi-Ventana. Añadir los siguientes `metadatos` de nuevo justo antes de `</application>` cerrar la etiqueta:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />
```

> Especificar el tamaño de la ventana por defecto.

Debe especificar los tamaños predeterminados de la configuración Multi-Ventana usando las etiquetas de `metadatos` / entradas adicionales en **dimens.xml**.

***dimens.xml*** muestra los valores por defecto tomados de la aplicación Galería de ***Samsung***, se ajusta a sus necesidades si es necesario. ;).

Añadir los `metadatos` de nuevo justo antes de `</application>` cerrar la etiqueta:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:resource="@dimen/app_defaultsize_w" />

<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:resource="@dimen/app_defaultsize_h" />

<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W" android:resource="@dimen/app_minimumsize_w" />

<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H" android:resource="@dimen/app_minimumsize_h" />[/code]
```

y en su **dimens.xml**:

```
[code]<dimen name="app_defaultsize_w">632.0dip</dimen>

<dimen name="app_defaultsize_h">598.0dip</dimen>

<dimen name="app_minimumsize_w">632.0dip</dimen>

<dimen name="app_minimumsize_h">598.0dip</dimen>
```

> Documentación adicional esta en english pero de seguro aporta más información para amigarse con la funcionalidad.

- [Video developer samsung](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs/Designing-For-The-Galaxy-Note-Creating-Multi-Window-Apps)
- [Documentación developer android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html)
- Pregunta en [SO English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929315/android-n-application-does-not-support-multi-window/35929316)

Espero que esta guía te ayude y solucione el problema y a todos que pasen por algo similar.

Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Hola amigo me parece que te refieres a MultiTasking op MultiWindow, similar a lo que se tiene en iOS 9,

Lo que se necesita principalmente es:

- Cambiar tu targetSDK a 24 (puede ser 23 o menos con ciertas consideraciones).
- Agregar la propiedad `android:resizableActivity="true"` dentro del AndroidManifest.xml, esto puede ser para la aplicacion o para una Activity.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

Comment: Muy buenas Elena, probaré eso, pero me parece que es más por Android N, yo me refiero Samsung en su capa de personalización android 4,5,6 le da soporte a multiventana, voy siguiendo investigando